# PDO and the use of filtering tools like htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, pdo

I've been reading up on PDO and I have noticed the absence of the use of input filtering mechanisms like `htmlspecialchars()` in all the examples.

**The question**: Does using PDO *obsolete* the use of `htmlspecialchars()` and the like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what data you are saving. If you are saving data to directly display on your website, then obviously you'd need `htmlspecialchars()` and the likes of it. PDO obsolete the use of `mysql_real_escape()` and such by using prepared statements.

**As an iron law, every string must be escaped for its proper destination: HTML strings undergo HTML escaping, MySQL strings undergo MySQL escaping etc.**

Comment: Ok cool. I am taking data from a form and (ultimately) putting it in a mysql db via PDO...so if I understand you correctly @Rikudo Sennin, i do not have to use mysql_real_escape any more.  Thanks!